# How can I get the focus event trigger?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using only javascript, I'd like to know if a focus event was triggered by a click on a "select" tag, or if it was triggered by a tab. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can check it like this :

```js
  const select = document.getElementById("number");
    select.addEventListener("keyup", myFunction);
  function myFunction(e) {
  if(e.key === 'Tab'){
  console.log('I am a focus event was triggered by using tab')  
  }  
  }
  select.addEventListener("mousedown", myFunction2);
  function myFunction2(){
    console.log('I am a focus event was triggered by a click')  
  }
```

```html
<label for="cars">Choose a number:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="number" >
    <option value="volvo">1</option>
    <option value="saab">2</option>
    <option value="opel">3</option>
    <option value="audi">4</option>
  </select>
```